# android ( resize screen)

Tags: android, fullscreen, screen-orientation

I want to ask my application only for 4.0" and 4.3" screens mobile.

When I install it to 3.0" or 3.4" mobile my full screen does not appear.

Some buttons and labels  went down and not seen.

And finally I want to learn how I do this application for all mobile?

Can I do this in code ? or in manifest file?

Comment: What do you mean by ` how I do this application for all mobile `?

Comment: I mean i want to run this app on 3.0" screen mobile or 4.3" screen mobile.but it s look like good on 4.3" but not good on 3.0" because my layout big for 3.0" screen ,it does not auto size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask my application only for 4.0" and 4.3" screens mobile.

Using http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html, you can limit your app to devices with specific screen sizes.

> When I install it to 3.0" or 3.4" mobile my full screen does not appear. Some buttons and labels went down and not seen.

Strange! Are you using absolute pixel values in your layouts? If you are not, the layouts will scale on any phone. Only it will not look very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run application for 4.0 and 4.3. you need to install 4.3. then you can run 4.0 also. if you install 3.0 or 3.4 it will run 3.4 and below the version only. it won't work for hiegher versions otherthan 3.4.

Comment: I think the subject is screen-sizes, not OS(?) versions.